# How to use SkeltonView using RxSwift, RxCocoa

Tags: swift

I wanna use [SkeltonView](https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView) in my app. But, it was described that we need to confirm to SkeltonTableViewDataSource to use it in README.

Is there any one who knows to use SkeltonView like `tableView.rx.items`.

```
If you want to show the skeleton in a UITableView, you need to conform to SkeletonTableViewDataSource protocol.

public protocol SkeletonTableViewDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numSections(in collectionSkeletonView: UITableView) -> Int // Default: 1
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, cellIdentifierForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ReusableCellIdentifier
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, skeletonCellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? // Default: nil
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, prepareCellForSkeleton cell: UITableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```